# getting null value in my table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, autocomplete, foreign-keys, jquery-autocomplete

I am creating employee pay roll application. In that i am having two models one is employee and another is salary. I have added foreign key to get the employee_id in salaries table and to get the employee name in _form.html.erb(salaries) using the gem '[rails3-jquery-autocomplete](https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete)'. I have followed all the steps in that gem. But foreign key relationship is not working. I am getting **null value** in the field employee_id  in salaries table. 
'

Here i have attached my model,view,controller,routes and everything. Kindly check it.

**My Models**

**** Salary.rb****

```
class Salary < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :employee, :foreign_key => "employee_id"

  attr_accessible :basic, :da, :effective_from, :effective_to, :employeesalary, :hra, :ca, :sa, :employee_id

end
```

**Employee.rb**

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :salaries, :foreign_key => "employee_id"

  attr_accessible :address, :age, :branch, :city, :date_of_birth, :designation, :employee_end_date, :employee_start_date, :gender, :name

end
```

**My Controllers**

**salaries_controller.rb**

```
 class SalariesController < ApplicationController

  autocomplete :employee, :name, :display_value => :name, :full => true

  def new

    @salary = Salary.new    
  end

  def create

   @salary = Salary.new(params[:salary])

    if @salary.save
      flash[:success] = "Created a new month salary!"
      redirect_to salaries_path
    else
      flash[:error] = "Couldn't Create salary"  
      render  'new'
    end
  end

  def index

    @salary = Salary.order('created_at DESC').paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)

  end

  def show

    @salary = Salary.find(params[:id])
    @employee =Employee.all

  end

end
```

**employees_controller.rb**

```
class EmployeesController < ApplicationController

   def new

    @employee = Employee.new
    @salary = @employee.salaries.build

  end

  def create


   @employee = Employee.new(params[:employee])

    if @employee.save
      flash[:success] = "Created Employee Successfully!"
      redirect_to employee_path(@employee)
    else
      flash[:error] = "Couldn't Create a Employee"  
      render  'new'
    end
  end

  def index

    @employee = Employee.order('created_at DESC').paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)

  end

  def show

    @employee = Employee.find(params[:id])
  end


end
```

**routes.rb**

```
resources :salaries do
   get :autocomplete_employee_name, :on => :collection
   end

  resources :employees
```

**_form.html.erb(salaries)**

```
<%= form_for @salary do |f| %>

<%= f.hidden_field :employee_id, :id => "real_employee_id" %>

 <span class="help-block">Enter the Employee name</span> 

<%= autocomplete_field_tag 'throwaway_employee', '',
          autocomplete_employee_name_salaries_path,
          :size => 75, :id_element => '#real_employee_id' %>
```

**application.js**

```
//= require jquery

//= require jquery_ujs

//= require autocomplete-rails

//= require_tree .
```

I have checked throughly but can't find the error. Kindly help me to get out of this issue.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Can you post the full text of the error message please.

Comment: @JohnC: Yesterday only i have faced that error(undefined method model_name for Nil Class). But, now foreign key relationship is not working...

Comment: Can you post the file in which the `_form.html.erb` is rendered?

Comment: @Pavan: index.html.erb

Comment: What happens when you change this line `<%= form_for @salary do |f| %> `to `<%= form_for @salary,url: { action: "create" } do |f| %>`?

Comment: @Pavan: The same action takes place. autocomplete is not working

Comment: @Pavan: still i am getting null value for the field employee_id(foreign key) in my salaries table. kindly help me to get out of this issue.

Comment: What happens when you change this line `<%= form_for @salary do |f| %>` to `<%= form_for @employee do |f| %>`?

Comment: @Pavan: i gave and it shows the error "undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a play with this code tonight and I think I know what might be happening.

When you start typing in an employee name a **green** list of names pops up.  If you just hit enter straight away the form takes whatever you have typed so far and uses it to look up the name.  This fails because the name is incomplete.  As you have no validation on the employee id the form works and a null employee id is saved.

What you need to do is to use the down arrow key or mouse to select one of the names.  When you do that the name will change to **light green** and the text in the text box will be replaced with the full name.
Then when you submit the form the match is found and everything works!

So your code works, you are just using the GUI incorrectly.

You should also add this line to your salary.rb file:

```
validates :employee_id, presence: true
```

That's my theory.  Please try it out and let us know how you go.

Comment: In log/development.log i couldn't get the employee id. Here my log      Started POST "/salaries" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-19 15:24:11 +0530
Processing by SalariesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"1dDwYdi0NAUkTuPj+SKhzU52DMm23vx7dL8pjebFV+A=", "salary"=>{"employee_id"=>"", "effective_from(1i)"=>"2013", "effective_from(2i)"=>"9", "effective_from(3i)"=>"15", "basic"=>"6500", "da"=>"500", "hra"=>"500", "ca"=>"500", "sa"=>"500"}, "throwaway_employee"=>["Yogesh"], "commit"=>"Confirm Salary"}

Comment: JohnC: Some code to save in controller means something like this ah " @salary.employee.save " ?.

Comment: John C: Sir, sorry for my inconvenience and thanks for your support.

Comment: John C: Sir, Its holly my blunder in application.js file i have missed this line "//= require jquery-ui". Just now i corrected my blunder.